# XSLT and for-each

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML message like the following:

```
<message>
<line number="1"><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li></line>
<line number="2"><li>x</li><li>y</li><li>z</li>
</line>
<line number="3"><li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li>
</line>
</message>
```

I am wondering why the following XSLT does not return the `<li>` elements, but only what is inside `<li></li>`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="/message/line">

line <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>: <xsl:value-of select="."/>

  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For example: `line 1: 123` instead of `line 1: <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li>`

Answer (score 2):

That's what `xsl:value-of` does: it returns the string value of a node. If you want it kept as a tree, use `xsl:copy-of`.

Incidentally, there aren't any tags in XSLT-land. It only sees nodes. The tags were turned into nodes by the XML parser before XSLT swung into action.

Comment: Thanks very much - this is what I was looking for.